# Why are installer variables for help text not resolvable?

Tags: install4j

Today I wanted to include an installer variable to the help text for a leading lable but the output in the popup text said, that the installer variable could not be resolved. When I put the installer variable directly as the text of the label it could be resolved. Is this a bug or are installer variable in generally not resolvable for the popup help text of leading labels and other components with an helper text?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that the installer variable was not defined at the time that the screen was constructed. As of install4j 6.0 there is no mechanism that updates the text when the variable definition changes, but this is planned for a future release.